# Moving SVG objects using Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am currently working on a animated SVG, this includes elements being rotated, moving, etc.
I am facing the problem that I am unable to move certain elements that use a path to get its position.

My existing Javascript code moves some elements using the x attribute, this is working, but still leaves the elements that work with the paths.

Example SVG object:

```
<path id="XMLID_1418_" d="m1247.8 933c0 17.3-14 31.4-31.4 31.4-17.3 0-31.4-14-31.4-31.4h62.8z" class="st103"></path>
```

Margins, position or adding a x attribute doesnt move it, how can I do this?

Comment: path elements don't have an x attribute, apply a transform to the path instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the element in a 'g' element and translate that object to move the whole path.

`<g transform="translate(x,y)"></g>`

Comment: I am going to try right now, I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: don't need to wrap it, you can apply a transform to the path directly.

Comment: Thank you Evers, it is working. I have tried this using CSS, obviously a attribute has to be used. :)
Robert, thank you for the additional information, but the path is in a group with more elements.